# ValueError: root_directory must be an absolute path: Error when access directory in ADLS from Synapse Workspace

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, great-expectations

When trying to access ADLS directory with the following PySpark code in Apache Spark I get the error:

```
ValueError: root_directory must be an absolute path. Got abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/ instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/great_expectations/core/usage_statistics/usage_statistics.py", line 262, in usage_statistics_wrapped_method
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

The code that gives the above error when I'm trying to access the directory is as follows:

```
data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
                    datasources={"my_spark_datasource": my_spark_datasource_config},
                    store_backend_defaults=FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults(root_directory='abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/'),
                )

context = BaseDataContext(project_config=data_context_config)
```

When I change the code to

```
data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
                    datasources={"my_spark_datasource": my_spark_datasource_config},
                    store_backend_defaults=FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults(root_directory='/abfss://root@adlspretbiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/LANDING/'),
                )
```

I get the following error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/abfss:'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

When I enter the following code

```
data_context_config = DataContextConfig(
                    datasources={"my_spark_datasource": my_spark_datasource_config},
                    store_backend_defaults=FilesystemStoreBackendDefaults(root_directory='/'),
                )

context = BaseDataContext(project_config=data_context_config)
```

I get the error message:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/expectations'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

However, I don't have a directory called '/expectations

As a side note I'm trying to execute Great_Expectations.

Answer (score 0):

The developers of Great_Expectations have informed me that this error will be fixed a new release of the Great_Expectations